# Using Stylus CSS preprocessor, embedding SVG in a background-image property with the ability to set the fill attribute via a variable

Tags: css, svg, stylus

Using Stylus preprocessor, I'm looking to embed inline SVG code (not external files) in `background-image` properties in a manner that will allow me to set the `fill` attribute of the SVG in the CSS via a Stylus variable.

I've looked into Stylus' `url` and `embedurl` methods, but it seems to me that they only work on external files, and I don't know how I'd integrate my need to set the fill attribute with them.

### Current (Working but Nasty) Attempt

I have a working solution, but it is ugly and I'm convinced there is an easier and cleaner way that I haven't been able to find.

My current efforts follow with the irrelevant parts of the encoded SVG removed.

```
myColorVariable = #FF0000

...

background-image 'url("[...]fill%3D%22%23%s%22[...]")' % unquote(slice(unquote(""+myColorVariable),1))
```

With a full SVG:

```
myColorVariable = #FF0000

...

background-image 'url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20data-icon%3D%22thumb-up%22%20width%3D%2232%22%20height%3D%2232%22%20data-container-transform%3D%22scale%281%201%20%29%20translate%280%20%29%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2032%2032%22%20fill%3D%22%23%s%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M17.688%200c-.4%200-.688.313-.688.813v2.78c0%203-2.912%206.32-4.813%208.22C11.287%2012.513%2010.2%2013%209%2013v17s2%201%205%201h11.187c.9%200%201.725-.605%202.125-1.405%200%200%203.8-10.494%204.5-13.594.1-.4.094-.61.094-.81.1-1.2-.92-2.19-2.22-2.19H22.5c-1.2%200-2.19-1.112-2.19-2.312C20.31%209.488%2022%207%2022%204V2.5C22%201.1%2020.9%200%2019.5%200h-1.814zM0%2013l2%2019h5V13H0zm5%2016c.6%200%201%20.4%201%201s-.4%201-1%201-1-.4-1-1%20.4-1%201-1z%22/%3E%3C/svg%3E")' % unquote(slice(unquote(""+myColorVariable),1))
```

#### Issues:

- It only seems to work with latest versions of Stylus. For example, it doesn't work on Codepen, but it works in my setup with Grunt, and typing the following into the ["Try Stylus Online" section of the Stylus website](http://stylus-lang.com/try.html) shows it outputting what is expected.

  ```
  c = #FF0000
  cString = "" + #FF0000
  cMinusHash = slice(cString, 1)
  cWithEncodedHash = "%23" + cMinusHash

  unquote(cWithEncodedHash);
  ```
- I have to have a series of string manipulation methods on my variable to try and cast it to a string and remove the hash tag of the hex color. I have to remove the hash tag of the hex color because the hash tag needs to be encoded and is thus included in the SVG string. The necessity for both of the `unquote` methods doesn't make sense to me, but it's what works. Also, the concatenation of an empty string with the color variable seems like a very hacky way to cast the color to a string, but I was unable to find a better way.
- The SVG code has to have its quotes (double or single) encoded for the Stylus string interpolation to work, which is added hassle on top of the encoding that cross-browser compatibility requires.

In case it's helpful, [here is my Codepen](http://codepen.io/rjaillet/pen/zKJwjm?editors=0100) I made attempting to demonstrate my solution that works in my setup but not on Codepen.

Please forgive me if I omit necessary information or do something wrong; this is only my second question here. I'm happy to fix whatever I need to.

Thanks!

Comment: In codepen doesn't work your code because `slice` function, the Stylus version in codepen is 0.53.0 and `slice` added in 0.54.0. In Chrome works fine without convert the color in string: http://codepen.io/blonfu/pen/PGxqzv. In Firefox an chrome works with` rgb()` but in this case must be a string and then unquote because when compile stylus the convert colors to hexadecimal: http://codepen.io/blonfu/pen/ORayRb. In IE doesn't work neither